# go has a built in "print" function?

Tags: go

I cam across some code today that suprised me with a 'print' that wasn't defined.  After a little playing I determined that you can just use a print to get things dumped to the console

e.g.

```
 print("Hello World")
```

So it seems to be some sort of builtin but I can't find any reference to it (and I thought the go rules were lowercase functions never imported anyway)

Is this well known and if so are there other convenience functions or am I just very, very confused?

One other point -- this print doesn't use the magic formatting tricks (%v) of fmt.Printf -- If you print maps or structs you seem to get their address.

Answer (score 13):

`print` and `println` *are* [defined here](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers).

Their purpose is [explained here](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Bootstrapping).

Answer (score 13):

You are right, and someone else has already complained about it. It's been added to the built-in documentation for the next Go release (go1.2).

> [Package builtin](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/builtin/)
>
> [func print](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/builtin/#print)
>
> ```
> func print(args ...Type)
> ```
>
> The `print` built-in function formats its arguments in an
>   implementation-specific way and writes the result to standard error.
>   Print is useful for bootstrapping and debugging; it is not guaranteed
>   to stay in the language.
>
> [func println](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println)
>
> ```
> func println(args ...Type)
> ```
>
> The `println` built-in function formats its arguments in an
>   implementation-specific way and writes the result to standard error.
>   Spaces are always added between arguments and a newline is appended.
>   Println is useful for bootstrapping and debugging; it is not
>   guaranteed to stay in the language.

Comment: Great! Meanwhile you could declare `const print := fmt.Println`

Comment: @ColonelPanic: `const print := fmt.Println` is a compiler error. `fmt.Println` is not a constant. Write `var print = fmt.Println` or `print := fmt.Println`.

Comment: `print` and `println` have been in Go since the beginning. They are defined in the language specification.